# I keep getting Spotify "can't play this" error in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, google-chrome, pulseaudio, spotify, audio-player

So after the first time installing and actually trying Ubuntu. I love it, especially everything is now as how i want it to be. But there's just one thing that bothers me: Spotify keeps showing error "Can't play this. If you have file in local" for every single song. I'm sure it's not my Premium subscription nor my account because web playing music in chrome via open.spotify.com is totally fine. I've done quite a bit research and found out that this error is, i think, related to the audio system of Ubuntu. Must have been something about audio configuration that messes up Spotify. I've already change audio bit rate depth and sampling rate to default by changing to

```
; default-sample-format = s16le 
; default-sample-rate = 44100
```

in

```
etc/pulse/daemon.conf
```

but that shows nothing. Also I haven't changed anything much beside adding this

```
set-default-sink 3
set-default-source 3
```

to

```
etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Please help me.
Thank you for your precious time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow spotify to play audio in Ubuntu Store.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered this issue on my new Ubuntu system i.e 20.04.
The solution is pretty simple,

1. Go to Ubuntu App Store
2. Go to installed apps
3. Find and click on Spotify
4. Click on permissions on the top right
5. In the play and record option, select anyone provided there, for me i tried "pulseaudio:service" firstly and it worked like a charm.